# Watching a Directory for new csv files

Tags: java, csv, directory

Hell everyone,

I'm following this tutorial [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/notification.html)to create a watch for Directory and make some actions if a new csv file received.
I'm using the code in there [second example](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/displayCode.html?code=http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/examples/Email.java).

the problem in the lines:

```
//Verify that the new file is a csv file.
            try {
                Path child = dir.resolve(filename);
                System.out.println(Files.probeContentType(child));
                if (!Files.probeContentType(child).equals("application/vnd.ms-excel")) {
                //if (!Files.probeContentType(child).equals("text/csv")) {

                //if (Files.toString().endsWith(".csv")) {
                    System.err.format("New file '%s' is not a csv text file.%n", filename);
                    continue;
                }
            } catch (IOException x) {
                System.err.println(x);
                continue;
            }
```

when i use :

```
                    //if (!Files.probeContentType(child).equals("text/csv")) {
```

it does not detect the file but since I expect using different csv files that come from different sources not only excel. Is this the correct way to detect file type?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
filename.endsWith(".csv");
```

Comment: Actually i did tried that " Sorry i did not mention" but it still did not work. the System.out.println(Files.probeContentType(child)); display : application/vnd.ms-excel

Comment: Is filename String ??

Comment: Path filename = ev.context();

Comment: then try child.endsWith(".csv");